# Best-pratice to write smart contract

Tags: erc-20, solidity

I need your help to write a smart contract to the best way and avoid an attack.

I have a function that user can call to buy Service and update the state.
Now, I am confused, it will be different if I change the state before or after the user transferring tokens with the function `transferFrom`.

For example:

```
 function buyService(uint256 IDService,address ServiceUser,uint256 costService) public  {   
    Status storage s=StatusUsers[IDService][ServiceUser];
    require(s.state == StateService.Init);      
    token.transferFrom(ServiceUser,owner,costService);      
    s.state=StateService.Paid;
    s.cost=costService;
    emit Paid();   
}
```

Comment: [Use the Checks-Effects-Interactions Pattern](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/security-considerations.html#use-the-checks-effects-interactions-pattern).

Comment: So I read about checks-effects-interactions Patterns and compare to what I understood, this code should be the last step of my function token.transferFrom(ServiceUser,owner,costService);. I am right?

Comment: This is a very good guide https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/

Comment: I have read this guide before long time ago .I just want to know if first I need to update the state and the interaction with the other contract would be in the end of the function .

Comment: @RonBerreby It really depends on what are you trying to achieve. Does the token during `transferFrom` needs to invoke your contract again? ie does your contract need to support reentrancy? Is it possible for a third party to make an arbitrary call from `transferFrom`?

Comment: I will give you a little explain of what I am trying to achieve.I have a Service and Token ERC20 Smart Contract.To get our service user need to invoke our contract and buy the service.When the user will call the function "buyservice" that will invoke the token smart contract and transfer tokens from user to a another wallet and update the state to "Paid" .If the state is Paid we will invoke again the contract and call another function to send our service to the user and update the state to "Receive". I have many other functions on my contract and I want to avoid an re-entry attack.

Comment: If It depends to me I think its more logic to transfer the tokens without error and after update the state.